# Prevent jquery click function if div clicked within div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitters bootstrap modal with my own backdrop, this is so the modal behaves like the Pinterest modal (body-noscroll and scrollbars match modal height).

My code to close the modal is:

```
$(".modal-container").click(function(e) {
    $('.modal-container .modal').modal('hide');
});
$('.modal').live('hidden', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    $('.modal-container').hide();
});
```

When the user clicks inside `.modal` however, this function still runs, which I dont want. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

So the html is:

```
<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Css is:

```
.modal-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    width: 630px;
    margin-left: -315px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    z-index: 1052;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of this: $('.modal').live('hidden',...);  ?

Comment: I have other small bits of code running that I omitted for simplicity. This runs when the twitter code closes the modal

Comment: @adeneo oh yes that is a simple solution that I always forget. `:P`

Comment: @adeneo where would I put that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edited out my `e.stopPropagation` answer as it won't work with event delegation which OP requests*

As commented by @Adeneo, a usually simpler solution is to just check if the [event target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/), that is, the element which originated the click event corresponds to the one that you attached the click handler to:

```
$(".modal-container").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) $('.modal-container .modal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Can I use this in a 'live' context? I use infinite scroll to load more modals on the page after its loaded.

Comment: @bluedaniel   Ya, use delegation with on:  $(".modal-container").on('click','.modal',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

Comment: Yes, you can. It should run just fine as well.

Comment: I also have Twitter intents inside the .modal, is there a way to let these run with this solution?

Comment: This solution shouldn't affect anything other than your custom modal, or does it?

Comment: It doesn't! I thought I had tried propagation but this works so far.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just reminded that you can't call e.stopPropagation from a delegated handler, my bad.

Comment: if (e.target === this) works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to not only help me with this but also explain it in a way that will help me moving forwards. Thanks!